# Every upload & download getting notification "Amplify transfer service is running"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, notifications, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS Amplify as my app backend to store image and video. In every upload and download I'm getting the above notification.

**Questions**

**1.** How to stop that notification?

**2.** Can we customize that notification to show the upload & download progress?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reaching out!

For #1, There’s a more detailed discussion of that issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/1803.  In the meantime, while it is being addressed on our end, you can apply the workaround in that issue where you manually stop the TransferService once the upload/download is finished: stopService(Intent(context, TransferService::class.java)).

For #2, Support for showing upload/download progress in the foreground notification is currently not supported. You can open up a GitHub issue in our repo (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android) for general discussion so that we can gauge customer desire for this feature.